# How to setup gitlab-runner to run docker command into gitlab-ci?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to configure gitlab runner in order to uses docker command into my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

I have run 2 containers to do that :

- `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`
- `gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine`

I have set my registered runner with privilege mode :

```toml
[[runners]]
  name = "first runner"
  url = "http://my.domain.com:8484/"
  token = "mySecretToken"
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "http://my.domain.com:8484/"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:lts-alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

My pipeline work fine to build and run tests. Now i want to build nginx docker container with my node builded files.

When i just run `docker version` command, there was an error :

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        831ebea
 Built:             Tue Dec 15 04:28:35 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.24/version: dial tcp: lookup docker on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Maybe it's an error into my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```yaml
services:
  - name: docker:dind

stages:
    - construction

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  # See https://github.com/docker-library/docker/pull/166
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

deploiement:
  stage: construction
  image: docker:latest
  before_script:
    - docker version
  script:
    - echo "test"
```

**How can i configure my runner to execute docker commands ? Is my runner setup wrong** ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: And what's happen if you add `volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]`.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4794) can help?

Answer (score 2):

According to [@Dr Claw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12962618/dr-claw) and [@vpalmerini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11933925/vpalmerini) comments, it necessary to add docker.sock into volume and remove variables and service. See [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4794).

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```yaml
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

before_script:
  - df
  - cat /etc/resolv.conf
  - cat /etc/hosts

deploiement:
  image: docker:latest
  before_script:
    - docker version
  script:
    - docker info
```

My `config.toml`:

```toml
[[runners]]
  name = "Synology premier runner"
  url = "http://my.domain.com:8484/"
  token = "1UsxGPQmxht6zHPb_y2b"
  executor = "docker"
  clone_url = "http://my.domain.com:8484/"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "node:lts-alpine"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Thanks you very much for your answers [@Dr Claw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12962618/dr-claw) and [@vpalmerini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11933925/vpalmerini) !

Comment: Saved me hours as well! No way to run docker in docker on GitLab runners without setup the volumes configuration and running it with privileged = true